# Nginx reverse proxy to Wordpress on an URI

Tags: wordpress, symfony, redirect, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a Symfony 2.5.X app running on an nginx server. I will call it **domain.com**.

The /news URI within that server is configured as a reverse proxy to a remote machine, where I run Wordpress blog on nginx server again. I will call it **blog.domain.com**.

**domain.com**'s configuration looks like that:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain.com;

  set $project_path /home/webserver/prod.domain.com;
  root $project_path/web;

  error_log /home/webserver/prod.domain.com/app/logs/nginx_error.log;
  access_log /home/webserver/prod.domain.com/app/logs/nginx_access.log;

  charset utf-8;
  client_max_body_size 65m;

  # Some extra speed
  open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=20s;
  open_file_cache_valid 30s;
  open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
  open_file_cache_errors on;

  # Reverse-proxy all /news calls to remote machine
  location ~ /news?(.*) {

    access_log off;

    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_set_header        Host                    blog.domain.com;  # without it it doesn't work
    #proxy_set_header        Host                    $http_host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       http;
    proxy_set_header        X-Custom-Secret         6ffe3dba7213c678324a101827aa3cf22c;

    proxy_redirect          off;
    proxy_buffering         off;
    #proxy_intercept_errors  on;

    proxy_pass http://blog.domain.com:80;
    break;
  }
  # Default URLs
  location / {
    try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
  }

  # Error pages (static)
  #error_page 403                 /errorpages/403.html;
  error_page 404                  /errorpages/404.html;
  #error_page 405                 /errorpages/405.html;
  error_page 500 501 502 503 504  /errorpages/5xx.html;

  # Don't log garbage, add some browser caching
  location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    expires max;
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    try_files $uri /app.php?$query_string;
  }
  location ~* ^.+\.(css|js)$ {
    expires modified +1m;
    add_header Pragma "private";
    add_header Cache-Control "private";
    etag on;
    try_files $uri /app.php?$query_string;
  }
  location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  # Disallow .htaccess, .htpasswd and .git
  location ~ /\.(ht|git) {
    deny all;
  }

  # Parse PHP
  location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    include                 fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param           HTTPS           off;
    fastcgi_pass            php;
  }
}
```

**blog.domain.com**'s configuration looks like that:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name blog.domain.com;

  root  /home/webserver-blog/news;

  access_log    /home/webserver-blog/logs/http_access.log;
  error_log     /home/webserver-blog/logs/http_error.log;

  charset utf-8;
  client_max_body_size 65m;

  # Some extra speed
  open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=20s;
  open_file_cache_valid 30s;
  open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
  open_file_cache_errors on;

  # Default URLs
  location / {
    # This never gets parsed as / is reserved for our main server
  }
  location ~* ^/news/(wp-content|wp-admin) {  # without this directive I didn't have any static files
    root /home/webserver-topblog/;
  }
  location ~* ^/news {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?args;
  }

  # Don't log garbage
  location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    expires max;
  }
  location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  # Disallow .htaccess or .htpasswd
  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }

  # Disallow logs
  location ~ ^/logs/.*\.(log|txt)$ {
    deny all;
  }

  # Parse PHP
  location ~ \.php$ {
      #if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
      try_files $uri =404;

      include        fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_pass   php;
  }
}
```

As you can figure out, my Wordpress resides in `/home/webserver-blog/news/`. I have a slightly modified index.php file in Wordpress that checks for `X-Custom-Secret` header, and if it's not present (or invalid), it forces a 301 redirection to **domain.com/news/**

Now I have tried several different approaches to get it running properly.

- First (and most obvious) was pointing the `root` of **blog.domain.com**'s to `/home/webserver-blog/` and allowing nginx to naturally pass the request URI to the subdirectory, `/news`. This worked quite well, yet it didn't allow me to utilize Wordpress' permalinks and just worked with query strings. Other strange behaviour it produced was actually exposing **blog.domain.com** in HTTP redirect if you called `/news` without trailing slash. Those redirects were quickly handled by my custom index.php, but still I want to avoid exposing **blog.domain.com** completely.
- Second (and pretty-much current) approach was again pointing the `root` of **blog.domain.com**'s directly to Wordpress' directory, `/home/webserver-blog/news/` and cheating all the requests for static files with `location ~* ^/news/(wp-content|wp-admin)` directive pointing it's root directory one levelel up. This worked for both permalinks and static files, but again - `/news/wp-login.php` gives me infinite redirects to *itself*, and `/news/wp-admin/` actually downloads the index.php file instead of parsing it (sends it as `application/octet-stream`)

I am completely out of ideas... Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I managed to come with a so-so solution. Far from being perfect or clean, but... well, it works.

**blog.domain.com**'s config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name blog.domain.com;

  root  /home/webserver-blog;

  access_log    /home/webserver-blog/logs/http_access.log;
  error_log     /home/webserver-blog/logs/http_error.log;

  charset utf-8;
  client_max_body_size 65m;

  # Some extra speed
  open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=20s;
  open_file_cache_valid 30s;
  open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
  open_file_cache_errors on;

  # Default URLs
  location ~* ^/news$ {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://domain.com/news/ permanent;   # ** HARDCODED production url
    break;
  }
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @redir;
  }
  location @redir {
    rewrite ^/news/(.*)$ /news/index.php?$1 last;
  }

  # Don't log garbage
  location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    expires max;
  }
  location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  # Disallow .htaccess or .htpasswd
  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }

  # Disallow logs
  location ~ ^/logs/.*\.(log|txt)$ {
    deny all;
  }

  # Parse PHP
  location ~ \.php$ {
    include                 fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param           HTTPS           off;
    fastcgi_pass            php;
  }
}
```

So the trick is I'm still operating on filesystem directories and not fancy all-the-way-around rewrites and redirects. `news/` still remains a physical directory in the filesystem that gets read with the `location /` directive from nginx. Previous issues with exposing the **blog.domain.com** domain on trying to access without slashes seem to be native nginx's behaviour - it sees a directory, it adds a slash at the end; and since it's `server_name` is set to **blog.domain.com**, here we go. Hardcoding production URL and putting that rule on top pretty much fixed the problem.

`@redir` location again enabled the Wordpress' permalinks nicely.

One more thing I have added to entire setup to prevent people form going directly on http://**blog.domain.com**/ is another `index.php` file stored directly in `/home/webserver-blog/`:

```
<?php
/*
 * domain.com redirector
 */
$production = 'http://domain.com/news/';

// Redirect nicely
if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== '/') {

  $target = sprintf('%s%s', $production, preg_replace('/^\//', null, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
  header('Location: ' . $target);
}
else header('Location: ' . $production);
```

...and, as mentioned before, few lines on top of Wordpress' original `index.php`:

```
<?php
/*
 *  wordpress loader
 */
$production = 'http://domain.com/news/';

// Allow only reverse-proxied requests
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_CUSTOM_SECRET']) or $_SERVER['HTTP_X_CUSTOM_SECRET'] !== md5('your-md5encoded-text-in-proxy_set_header-X-Custom-Secret')) {
  die(header('Location: ' . $production));
}
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/index-wp-org.php';
```

Ugly... but works.
I'd still be happy to hear nicer solutons. :)